# InnoDB File .\undo_001: 'aio write' returned OS error 0. Cannot continue operation

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2019

We installed Wamp 3.3.0 64 bit on Windows Datacenter Server 2019 and had nothing but problems with MySQL v8.0.30 crashing. Here are the details:

Description:

1. The server did NOT crash running a specific query.
2. The log file generated an error "2023-07-21T22:27:51.129125Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012646] **[InnoDB] File .\undo_001: 'aio write' returned OS error 0.**"
3. The MySQL attempted a backtrace and came back with "Cannot continue operation"
4. The MySQL instance crashed.
5. I expected MySQl would recover from this operation but it did not eventhough we have the Windows Service setting to Restart on both 1st and 2nd attempts.

It happens once a week but there is no way to reproduce. CPU spikes to 100% and then MySQL crashes. We then have to stop and start the service for it to recover. Brand new server 24GB ram with SSD drives 4 CPU Sockets and 16 Virtual Processors running on Hypervison with average CPU
of 28%

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
\Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.